# How to skip function for a certain amount of loops

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i am currently running a test on a leaderboard, for every 20 entries there is a "show more" button that the user has to press to show the next 20 entries. I created a "try if catch" method but it only seems to press the button once so then i added it to the loop of the test_leaderboard_entry method but its taking a very long time after all the "show more" buttons have been pressed. How could i change this to be quicker when the test is running, or could i change the show_more method to actually press all the buttons that appear?

```
public void show_more() throws Exception {
    try {
        if (show_more_button.isDisplayed()) {
            show_more_button.click();
            System.out.println("Selecting show more button");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Show more button not present");
    }
}

public void test_player_leaderboard_entry() throws Exception {
    int size = playerRows.size();
    Integer previous_total = 0;
    Integer previous_points = 0;
    String previous_user = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        show_more();

        //Position
        String position_first_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-position-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Points
        String points_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-points-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Username
        String username_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-player-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Row Number
        Integer row = i + 1;
        Integer point_player = Integer.parseInt(points_player);
        Integer total_of_won_and_looking_good = 0;

        //PICKS
        for (int pick_number = 1; pick_number < 5; pick_number++) {
            String pick_status = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/section[2]/section/div/ol/a[" + row + "]/li/div[3]/div[" + pick_number + "]/div")).getAttribute("data-qa-pick-state");
            //System.out.println(pick_status);
            if (Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 2 || Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 1) {
                total_of_won_and_looking_good = total_of_won_and_looking_good + 1;
            }
        }
        if (previous_total.equals(total_of_won_and_looking_good) && (previous_points > point_player)) {
            //Assert.assertTrue;
            System.out.println("Picks are the same, points are higher ");
        } else if (previous_total.equals(total_of_won_and_looking_good) && previous_points.equals(point_player)) {
            String prev_user = previous_user.toLowerCase();
            String use_player = username_player.toLowerCase();
            Assert.assertTrue(prev_user.compareTo(use_player) < 0);
            System.out.println("Picks are the same, points are the same, alpha order is correct ");
        }
        previous_total = total_of_won_and_looking_good;
        previous_points = point_player;
        previous_user = username_player;

        System.out.println("On row number " + row + " we find " + username_player + " in position " + position_first_player + " with " + total_of_won_and_looking_good + " correct picks and " + points_player + " points!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the URL to the site?

Answer (score 2):

you can skip the loop in the following way,

```
if ( ((i+1) % 20) == 0)
   show_more();
```

It will click at the time of multiple of 20 and skips other time.

Also, noticed that size value is not updated after click on show more button. It will not continue after the first 20 iterations.

You can change your code as given below to updated the count or size value,

```
if ( ((i+1) % 20) == 0){
   show_more();
   size = playerRows.size();
}
```

insert the above inside for loop by replacing the show_more method calling. It may work for you.